# После 'apt upgrade' надо перезагружать запущенные процессы?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, debian

Имею ввиду процессы использующие старые версии пакетов. Или перезагрузка происходит автоматически?

Answer (score 0):

Вроде не надо.

> Debian has a start-stop-daemon program that is invoked to stop, then
>   restart running process if necessary during a package upgrade.

https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/debian-faq/ch-uptodate.en.html